# kwargs argument must be a dict, but got tuples в Джанго

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Я хотел бы ограничить доступ простым пользователям к админке Джанго. Для этого в urls.py я написал следующий код:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from find_work import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

# Функция для проверки, является ли пользователь администратором
def is_admin(user):
    return user.is_authenticated and user.is_staff

# URL-шаблоны
urlpatterns = [
    # URL для административной панели, доступен только для администраторов
    path('admin/', user_passes_test(is_admin),(admin.site.urls))]
```

Однако этот код выводит следующую ошибку: 
TypeError: kwargs argument must be a dict, but got tuple. 
Как мне её исправить?

Comment: и хотелось бы ещё узнать: как  вызывать ошибку 403 в Этом случае, если пользователь не админ?

Comment: Уберите запятую перед (admin.site.urls) наверное?

Comment: И вообще вся эта проверка бессмысленна, потому что Django выполняет её сам по умолчанию и вы просто делаете двойную работу. У простых пользователей и так по умолчанию нет доступа к админке

Comment: да, им нужно ввести пароль, но прикол в том что перед обычным пользователем открывается форма для входа в админку.  Так что найдутся гении которые через кликеры всё-таки подберут пароль. Я это делаю для перестраховки.  Когда я убираю запятую, у меня возникает ошибка : 
'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Просто не надо ставить слишком простой пароль, и тогда никто ничего никогда не сможет подобрать. Вы занимаетесь чем-то бессмысленным

Comment: Более того, в стандартных настройках Django по умолчанию включена проверка сложности пароля, так что, если вы сами осознанно не отключили её, то переживать о подборе нет смысла

Comment: нет, я просто пытаюсь скрыть админку от простых пользователей

Comment: Простые пользователи не увидят админку без знания пароля. А в том, что они увидят форму входа, ничего страшного нет

Comment: А, я осознал в чём дело, декоратор это же для вьюх, а admin.site.urls это не вьюха. Здесь нужно писать более сложный код, что-то типа такого https://stackoverflow.com/q/66673368